# Which partitionKeyPath should be used for frequently changed small data in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The documentation to the [partitionKeyPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview) for the Cosmos DB only point to large data and scaling. But what is with small data which frequently changed. For example with a container with a TTL of some seconds. Is the frequently creating and removing of logical partitions an overhead?

Should I use a static partition key value in this case for best performance?

Or should I use the `/id` because this irrelevant if all is in one physical partition?

Comment: Clarify what your goal is? "Should use" -- to achieve what exactly? Also, curious what is the use case for a small container with some seconds TTL.

Comment: The use case are different types of communication between different server nodes of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Use as granular LP key as possible. document `id` will do the job.

There are couple factors which affect performance and results you get from logical partition (LP) selection. When assessing your partitioning strategy you should bear in mind some limitations on the Logical and Physical Partition (PP) sizing.

LP limitation:

- Max 20GB documents

PP limitations:

- Max 10k RU per one physical partition
- Max 50GB documents

Going beyond the PP limits will cause partition split - skewed PP will be replaced and data split equally between two newly provisioned PPs. It has an effect on max RU per PP as max throughput is calculated based on `[provisioned throughput]/[number of PPs]`

I definitely wouldn't suggest using static LP key. *Smaller logical partitions - more maintainable and predictable performance of your container.*

Very specific and unique data consumption patterns may benefit from **larger LPs** but only if you're trying to micro-optimize queries for better performance and majority of queries you will be running will filter data by LP key. Moreover even for this scenario there is a high risk of a major drawback - hot partitions and partition data skew for containers/DBs with more than 50GB in size.